# How to get entire json report using camel metrics

Tags: apache-camel, codahale-metrics

I have configured below in camel-context.xml file.
I am able to see the reports well presented in hawtio.

However, I would like to get the actual camel metrics generated json report logged to my application log file.

Can anyone help me with how to achieve this?

Thanks
Ramesh

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

This is the code that returns the json on the server side: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-metrics/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/metrics/routepolicy/MetricsRegistryService.java

This will require a enhancement to support it to log the json to the logger. You are welcome to log a JIRA ticket: http://camel.apache.org/support

Comment: Thanks Claus

I would like to get documentation on what exactly various factors like p999, m1_rate etc. mean in the generated json report

In addition, how can we get spanned times aligned to various reported metrics data

Comment: Read about dropwizards metrics what those values mean - https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/getting-started/